# android's messenger IPC outdated or not working

Tags: android, ipc, messenger

[I was following this tutorial from the android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) implementing IPC only for one way communication as given. I copied it exactly one to one and no mistakes or error while building or running. When I start the service using the provided `sayHello` method, the `Toast` doesn't appear.

After a lot of `Log.e`ing I found that the overriden method `onServiceConnected` of the `ServiceConnection` instance wasn't being run which probably should had been done when I invoke the `bindService(...)` method which I run in the Activity's `onCreate`, so the `onServiceConnected` should had run, but it didn't. I wonder if the mechanism has broken somehow but the IPC isn't working. Again I did copy it exactly from the docs from the activity code to service code to manifest code, but it still doesn't work. [Here is the sample app](https://ufile.io/fxr0tzwj). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: even a bit of comment would be helpful, atleast I'd know if this problem is not the code's issue?(to the upvoters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not outdated, because the docs would have mentioned something like `deprecated`.

I was also facing this problem, and the big mistake was I hadn't set the `android:enabled` property to `true`.After that I cleaned the project and then everything started turning red highlighted, e.g. the `AppCompactivity` was not available. So I invalidated cache and restarted and then everything worked.